# How to insert a text from a variable to a kivy label which is made by me?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I want to insert a text from a variable to a label which is made by me. I want to enter the date in the variable fuldate in to a label which is known as Date_lbl. But it gives an error like " NameError: name 'fulldate' is not defined". I tried a lot and I can't find a way to do this.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import datetime
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'width', '900')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '500')
Config.write()

month = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%B")
date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%w")

fulldate = (month+", "+date)

Builder.load_string("""
<SmoothLabel@Label>
    background_color: (0,0,0,0)
    background_normal: ''
    back_color: (255,255,255,1)
    border_radius: [18]
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (255,255,255,0.3)
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: self.border_radius

<Money_Manager>

    FloatLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height:150
        Image:
            pos: 0,350
            source:'image4.png'
            size: self.texture_size
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: False

        SmoothLabel:
            id: Total_Wealth
            text: "Total Wealth :"
            pos: 600,450
            size_hint: (.3, .2)

        SmoothLabel:
            id: Cash
            text: "Cash             :"
            size_hint: (.3,0.2)
            pos: 600,410

        SmoothLabel:
            id: Savings
            text: "Savings        :"
            size_hint: (.3,0.2)
            pos: 600,370

        SmoothLabel:
            id: Date_lbl
            text: fulldate""")

class Money_Manager(App, FloatLayout):
    def build(self):

        return self

Money_Manager().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way in your example, is to create a kivy property in your app

```py
class Money_Manager(App, FloatLayout):
    fulldate = StringProperty()
    def build(self):
        self.fulldate = (month+", "+date)
        return self
```

and access it from the `kv` file like this `text: app.fulldate`